# Cannot change includeInGlobalAddressList using Directory API

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-api-python-client, google-directory-api

I am trying to migrate a script from the Profiles API to the Directory API. Its purpose is to manage the visibility of certain Google Apps Domain users' contact information using the includeInGlobalAddressList attribute.

I can fetch the user objects, and am able to submit a patch request, but the change does not get made. The object returned from the patch method has the original value for includeInGlobalAddressList. There are some vague references to etags in the api documentation, but it's not clear to me if the etag is supposed to be included in the patch body or as an If-Match header. (if the answer to that is an If-Match header, then how am I supposed to pass that in using the python library?)

```
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build("admin", "directory_v1", http=http)
usersvc=service.users()
d=usersvc.get(userKey=userkey, projection="basic",fields="etag,id,includeInGlobalAddressList").execute()
visible = d['includeInGlobalAddressList']
# logic to decide what change elided. this is "transition from visible to invisible contact"
pch=json.dumps({'includeInGlobalAddressList': False, 'etag': d['etag']})
print pch
res=usersvc.patch(userKey=userkey, body=pch, fields="etag,id,includeInGlobalAddressList").execute()
print json.dumps(res, indent=4)
```

The result I get is:

```
{"includeInGlobalAddressList": false, "etag": "\"WIg4sZOp0a-9Z5MJXVMQx1SQW5A/avXX6NaPX78Y6qFG7S4TqKFMIEU\""}
{
    "includeInGlobalAddressList": true, 
    "etag": "\"WIg4sZOp0a-9Z5MJXVMQx1SQW5A/J0MuBtIvJoTcifknCMScMlyCQnc\"", 
    "id": "109793672165131484748"
}
```

This happens even if I do not use `fields` or pass the etag.

Comment: I don't think you should be converting the patch body to a string before passing it into the patch() method.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to do a GET before the PATCH request. The idea of PATCH is that only changed data is sent across the wire. Try:

```
service = build("admin", "directory_v1", http=http)
usersvc = service.users()
res = usersvc.patch(userKey=userkey, body={"includeInGlobalAddressList": False}, fields="id,includeInGlobalAddressList").execute()
print res
```

Comment: While that would save round trips if things worked otherwise, it does not help the fact that the PATCH method seems to not have any effect for this attribute. (and if part of the solution to that is to include the etag, I will need the GET to read the etag)

Comment: I see your sample code removed the erroneous json.dumps() that turned out to be the problem. But I wouldn't have noticed it if not for Eric's comment above